# how can you select a column (ie: 0, 1, 2, 3)in a list (python 3.3)

Tags: python, list, python-3.3

This is the code I have now:

```
def ImportFile(FileName):
    templist =[]
    fileHandle = open('keywords.CSV','r') # Open the file in read only mode
    # For each line in the file 
    for line in fileHandle: 
        File = line.strip() # Cleans the line of text and gets rid of newline characters etc
        fileHandle_list.append(temp.split(',')) # Converts the line of text into a list of items     which were seperated by ","
    return fileHandle_list

''' randomise list '''
def RandomiseList():
    # Go through picking an item at random until I have the whole list
    fileHandle_list = []
    for item in random.sample(keywords, len(keywords)):
        fileHandle_list.append(item)
        print(fileHandle_list)
    return fileHandle_list
```

here is where it will be placed.

I have tried loads of things and I can't get it to work, thanks for the help.

Comment: what is `temp` in line 7?

Comment: I think you have confused your own variables... what does `templist` do in your first function? `fileHandle_list` is not initialised, `temp` the same, `File` is not used... and what are `keywords` in your 2nd function? Gee, almost every line has a variable out of nowhere :/

Comment: `random.sample(keywords, len(keywords))` is already exactly what you want `fileHandle_list` to be in the second function. You could just return that. It'd probably be better to make a copy of `keywords` and `random.shuffle` that, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to randomise the order of rows in a csv file, then something like:

```
import csv
import random

with open('keywords.CSV', 'rb') as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    file_handle_list = sorted(csvin, key=lambda L: random.random())
```

Or separate it to load the list, then "shuffle" it later:

```
file_handle_list = list(csvin)
# other stuff
random.shuffle(file_handle_list)
```